# How to fix error with type declaration in class property?

Tags: php

When I run this code in VS code, I got this error message

```
class Product {
    private string $name;
    private string $type;
    private string $sku;
}
```

`syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)`

but not found in sublime text. Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work unless you're using a version of PHP below 7.4.0,
Typed properties were only introduced in 7.4.0 and you'd need to upgrade you PHP server or change your code to

```
class Product {
    
    private $name;
    private $type;
    private $sku;

}
```

Comment: I was updated version of PHP and the problem was fixed. Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: No worries, glad that solved it! :)